# Do the Sally Lockhart Mysteries have to be read in order?

Tags: suggested-order, sally-lockhart-mysteries

I have read *The Ruby in the Smoke*, the first book of Pullman's Sally Lockhart Mysteries. Today I found *The Tiger in the Well*, the third book, in a bargain bin full of fantasy books. I haven't read the second book yet, *The Shadow in the North*.

Should I read *The Shadow in the North* first, or can I read *The Tiger in the Well* without spoiling anything for myself?

---

*I'm aware this series is bordering on fantasy at the most, but I was pretty sure I'd get an answer here. I think most bookstores classify Pullman as a fantasy author on account of* His Dark Materials *and hate to break up an author's work across sections.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes, you most certainly do have to read them in order.**  Each story builds on the events and actions of the prior with years separating the novels.

If you read *The Tiger in the Well* [Book 3] before *The Shadow in the North* [Book 2], you would not only ruin elements of the second book for yourself, but you might not understand why certain things are happening the way they are.

With a series as rich and intense as this each book is a gift, so don't shortchange yourself... in other words: **If you are patient young padawan all will be revealed.**

Comment: Having read _The Shadow in the North_ just now, I am most grateful for your answer. Also, Mr. Pullman is a most cruel writer to his characters.

Comment: You're very welcome and you're very right. The next two books will drive you mad at times, but in a good way!